# Can improper/inadequate exhalation in humans trigger migraines?

Tags: biochemistry, medicine

Is there any relation between  one's breathing pattern and occurrence of headaches? How does inadequate exhalation affect humans?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems a better fit for Health.SE

Comment: I meant it in a general sense, was not seeking a personalized answer.

Comment: If so then please remove any reference to self and try to make the question interesting for the community at large.

Comment: I have reworded my question. Can it be re-opened?

Comment: It's still too broad for the format here. I would opt for Health. SE, another stack in the SE network